# Extract the maximum value from the last number in a hierarchyID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column with hierarchy IDs converted to strings in SQL Server. I need to add new hierarcyIDs for the new lines, but first I have to find the last child of the current ID. The hierarchyIDs are look like these:

```
/1/1/1/6/1/ 
/1/1/1/6/7/
/1/1/1/6/3/
/1/1/1/6/13/
/1/1/1/6/4/
```

As you can see, the maximum number is not equal with the count of the lines, so I can not use count()+1 unfortunately.

What I need to extract from this list is:

```
13
```

I only have experience in PL SQL, where it was easy to do this with regexp functions, but I can not find the solution in SQL Server.

Comment: it can not be a solution because I have different hierarchy ids as well in that column. I need to extract the maximum of the last numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some STRING operation as below to get your desired output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d3626332ec96e6ae103562164265c61)

```
WITH your_table(your_column)
AS
(
    SELECT '/1/1/1/6/1/' UNION ALL
    SELECT '/1/1/1/6/7/' UNION ALL
    SELECT '/1/1/1/6/3/' UNION ALL
    SELECT '/1/1/1/6/13/' UNION ALL
    SELECT '/1/1/1/6/4/'
)

SELECT
MAX(
    CAST(
        REVERSE(
            LEFT(
                REVERSE(LEFT(your_column,LEN(your_column)-1)),
                CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(LEFT(your_column,LEN(your_column)-1)) ,0) - 1
            )
        )
    AS INT
    )
)
FROM your_table
```

> Note: Data has to be as your sample data

Answer (score 1):

The creators of `hierarchyid` have anticipated your needs and have an officially supported solution for this.

```
declare @h table (h HIERARCHYID);

insert into @h (h)
values 
    ('/1/1/1/6/1/'),
    ('/1/1/1/6/7/'),
    ('/1/1/1/6/3/'),
    ('/1/1/1/6/13/'),
    ('/1/1/1/6/4/');

declare @parent HIERARCHYID = '/1/1/1/6/';
declare @maxChild HIERARCHYID = (
    select max(h)
    from @h
    where h.IsDescendantOf(@parent) = 1
);

-- ToString() added here for readability in the output;
-- it's not needed to be used as data.
select @parent.GetDescendant(@maxChild, null).ToString();
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getdescendant-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#b-inserting-a-row-as-a-greater-descendant-node).

Another way around this is to specify your own components to the hierarchyid yourself. I like to use the primary key values. For example, let's say that this data represents a company's org chart. If EmployeeID 1 is the CEO, 42 is the CFO (who reports to the CEO) and 306 is Accounting Manager (who reports to the CFO), the latter's hierarchyid would be `/1/42/306/`. Because the PK values are unique, the generated hierarchid is also unique.

Answer (score 0):

To give some ideas, 2 solutions.

The first one is for Sql Server 2017 and beyond.
The second for most versions below that.

> ```
> create table YourTable
> (
>   ID int identity(101,1) primary key,
>   hierarcyIDs varchar(100)
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into YourTable 
>  (hierarcyIDs) values
>  ('/1/2/3/4/5/')
> ,('/1/2/3/4/15/')
> ,('/1/2/3/4/10/')
> ,('/11/12/13/14/15/')
> ,('/11/12/13/14/42/')
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> [1] as id1,
> [2] as id2,
> [3] as id3,
> [4] as id4,
> max([5]) as id5,
> concat_ws('/','',[1],[2],[3],[4],max([5])+1,'') as nextHierarcyIDs
> FROM YourTable
>
> OUTER APPLY
> (
>   select *
>   from
>   ( select try_cast(value as int) as id
>     , row_number() over (order by (select 0)) rn
>     from string_split(trim('/' from hierarcyIDs),'/') s
>   ) src
>   pivot (max(id) 
>     for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
>   ) pvt
> ) anarchy
> group by [1],[2],[3],[4]
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | nextHierarcyIDs 
> --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | :---------------
>   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |  15 | /1/2/3/4/16/    
>  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  42 | /11/12/13/14/43/
> ```

> ```
> SELECT hierarcyIdLvl1to4
> , MAX(hierarcyIDLvl5) AS maxHierarcyIDLvl5
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT id, hierarcyIDs
>   , substring(hierarcyIDs, 0, len(hierarcyIDs)-charindex('/',
> reverse(hierarcyIDs),2)+2) AS hierarcyIdLvl1to4
>   , reverse(substring(reverse(hierarcyIDs),2,charindex('/',
>   reverse(hierarcyIDs),2)-2)) AS hierarcyIDLvl5
> FROM YourTable
> ) q
> GROUP BY hierarcyIdLvl1to4
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> hierarcyIdLvl1to4 | maxHierarcyIDLvl5
> :---------------- | :----------------
> /1/2/3/4/         | 5                
> /11/12/13/14/     | 42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7e713232c480bcd66d0b19359b9ecde)*